# Does Flash have support for the soft/discretionary hyphen?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, cs4

Out of the box, Flash CS4/AS3 doesn’t seem to support the soft hyphen / discretionary hyphen (&shy; / U+00AD). Is there some trick to getting it to work, or is it simply not there?

Answer (score 0):

Is your textfield htmltext? Not that this will necessarily work - but just wanted to check.

(I think there wasn't support for it in FP8 and below but I'm not sure about 9/10).

Comment: Sorry - that was a dumb question. If you're using &shy; then of course it's html text!